# How to setup a background service on a geolocated app

Tags: android, service

I'm developing a geolocation based app for Android. I'm still beginning to understand how the framework works, so I'm not really sure if I'm doing things right.

The app has some custom View classes that are created within Activity classes and Layout components and mostly only render data. There is also a single Service that gets GPS updates using the Location API, read/write data, handle data and send it to the Views using Broadcasts. The Service is supposed to run as long as the app itself, but keep working on background indefinitely when the app is minimized.

The service is started on the base activity (which all activities extend) using:

```
startService(new Intent(BaseActivity.this, MyService.class));
```

It then proceeds to do its thing on an overrided onCreate method and periodically sends Broadcasts with data which the Activities and the Views listen to independently.

For me it seemed like a good setup, but I'm not sure since I started have some ANR problems after it's been started for some time (I let it sit overnight for testing and open it in the morning to an ANR screen).

I've read around about BoundServices and IntentServices, but it looked to me that my setup makes more sense (even though this whole thing is a bit confusing for me). So, am I in the right path? Or is this ANR error a warning to change it?

Comment: [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) runs on Main thread in android . If you do long running task you will face the ANR. Also to make keep running background you need to use a Foreground  Service . Read about [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html) and [Background Location Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits.html).

Comment: Ok, i've read the links and it all makes sense. So, after all, it seems that all I need to do to keep it from crashing is creating a notification via Notification.Builder()? Also, do you believe it is ok that all my communication between Service and Activity/Views is made using Broadcasts? Any reason to avoid it? (couldn't find a better way to do so)

Comment: If communication is Frequent  Then you should consider using a listener or Bind `Activity` to `Service`.